# Numbers and units

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, numbers

I'm looking for a single word to describe the combination of a number and unit. For example, “6 watts” or “2.5 kilometers”. *Measurement* is the closest I’ve come, but sounds cumbersome. Does anyone know of a better word to express this idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word you want is *quantity*.

Answer (score 6):

You can often just use *quantity*. However, the term for a number which does not have a unit is *dimensionless quantity*, and the opposite term is *dimensional quantity*. So use *dimensional quantity* when it is important to make the distinction (and you don’t mind using a ten dollar word).[¹](http://www.scienceofbehavior.com/lms/mod/glossary/view.php?id=408&mode=letter&hook=D&sortkey=&sortorder=&fullsearch=0&page=8)

Comment: I'm having trouble imagining a context where it would be important to specify that a quantity is dimensionless or dimensional. Not saying they don't exist, I just can't think of one.

Comment: @Jeremy: in *X + 5 = 100* the values *5* and *100* could probably be called dimensionless quantities.

Comment: For examples of usage, try these searches of Wikipedia articles: [dimensionless quantity](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=dimensionless+quantity&fulltext=1) and [dimensional quantity](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=dimensional+quantity&fulltext=1).

Comment: @Jeremy: It's very important in scientific contexts to mention that a constant or quantity is dimensionless.

Comment: Interesting article giving the historical narrative of the evolution of measurement in science  -- http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/measurement-science/

Answer (score 2):

If OP wants to sound a bit technical, he could call them [metrics](http://management.about.com/cs/generalmanagement/g/metrics.htm) - *a set of measurements that quantify results*.