# Measurements without a dimension (raw number)

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

I'm translating some documents to English which deal with some measurements. Most of the measurements have a unit dimension (length is in meters, weight is in kilograms, etc) but some of them do not have a specific dimension, e.g. Number of samples.

What word to use to describe such measurements? The direct translation of the original terms leaves me with "undimensional", but I don't think that's it.

Comment: Related and opposite! http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48067

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually *number of samples* does have a unit, i.e. *samples*. So you could say:

> I have 101 samples

Just as you can say

> I ran 100 km.

So if you are counting something, e.g. samples, apples, people, etc., then use that as the unit.

A quantity without a unit is often a ratio, e.g. a ratio of length (metres) to width (metres) would have no units because metre/metre cancels out; although ratio is probably too broad a term, since it doesn't exclude units.

If you want to represent a number that has no dimension then [*dimensionless*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_quantity) is an accepted term.

Other possible terms:

- % (percent)
- ppm (parts per million)
- degrees

More are listed in the above linked Wikipedia article.

These all depend on what you are measuring.

Comment: completely agree, and meter : length :: apple: *quantity* or *count*.

Comment: Strangely, it can in fact be valid to measure things without dimensions. e.g. Frequency can be measured in "per seconds" (http://www.slideshare.net/mrrayner/62-describing-waves). But we tend to use "Hertz" instead, because that is an easier concept to grasp.

Comment: @Urbycoz 1/sec is a dimension. I'm not saying there aren't cases, but frequency is not one of them.

Comment: @Urbycoz - you can also relate any units into length/mass/time (and current). But it's easier to say Volt than kg⋅m^2⋅s^−3⋅A^−1

Comment: It's worth noting that "percent", "ppm", "degrees", etc. are not actually synonyms for "dimensionless", but rather are examples of dimensionless units.

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on the context. However, you could use *quantity* or *amount*, even *numbers* depending on the nature of the object.

It is also a practice to use the hash [#] symbol to represent 'number of'.

I would certainly not use *unidimensional* unless the focus is actually on that attribute and not the measurement itself.

All the above keeping in mind we are discussing the language part of the issue, not the technicalities.

@Matt: Thanks for the link.

Comment: PS: Not *raw number*, though. That expression is used in various other ways, like unsorted data, unedited data, etc.

Comment: Kris, the focus is exactly on the attribute :) Measurements are grouped by dimension, and I needed a title for the *dimensionless* group

Answer (score 0):

Such units for counting are called **cardinal** numbers.

Comment: In technical use cardinal numbers implies integer values, and the measurements I have are both integers (number of samples) and real numbers (coefficients)